# count the number of rows in query

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have two tables

**Ages:**

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 39 |
| Katherine | 25 |
| Leslie | 75 |
| Gary | 20 |
| Faith | 58 |

**City:**

| First_Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | New York |
| Katherine | Boston |
| Leslie | Miami |
| Pam | Seattle |
| Gary | Chicago |
| Faith | Santa Barbra |

`select distinct First_Name as missing_names from City minus select distinct Name from Ages`

This returns:

| missing_names |
| --- |
| Pam |

I want to count the number of items that are returned in missing_names

I have tried `select count(distinct First_Name) as missing_names from City minus select distinct Name from Ages` but this just returns 6 (not 1)

In other words, I want my final output to be:

| missing_names |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to count how many values are returned by the query '''select distinct First_Name as missing_names from City minus select distinct Name from Ages'''. In the example I included in my post, only 1 value is returned but I would like to automate that count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could write subquery on top of this.

Select count(*) from(
select distinct First_Name as missing_names from City minus select distinct Name from Ages
)